# How to get most common and least common value using sql?

Tags: sql

Input table:

```
a b c
1 2 1
1 2 1
1 2 2
1 3 1
1 3 3
1 3 3
2 2 5
2 2 5
2 2 7
2 3 5
2 3 8
2 3 8
```

Expected output:

```
a b min max
1 2 2 1
1 3 1 3
2 2 7 5
2 3 5 8
```

Logic: Group by `col a` and `col b`, get the least common and most common values from `col c`.

In above example for `a = 1` and `b = 2`, the least common value for col c is 2 and most common values for col c is 1, this is depicted in the first row of the output.

Currently i am able to count the occurence of each value by using the query

```
select a, b, c, count(c) from table group by a, b, c
```

Comment: The most common value can be calculated using the `mode()` function

Answer (score 0):

Very late answer, but I find it interesting (and fun).
You have not tagged any specific rdbms but since most databases can use CTEs:

```
with 
  counters as (
    select
      a, b, c, count(*) counter
    from tablename
    group by a, b, c
  ),
  minmax as (
    select
      a, b, min(counter) mincounter, max(counter) maxcounter
    from counters 
    group by a, b
  )    
select 
  c.a, c.b, 
  max(case c.counter when m.mincounter then c.c end) min,
  max(case c.counter when m.maxcounter then c.c end) max
from counters c inner join minmax m
on m.a = c.a and m.b = c.b and c.counter in (m.mincounter, m.maxcounter)
group by c.a, c.b
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5y4TeNJAgo7HNuk3xiFonW/0).
Results:

```
| a   | b   | min | max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1   | 2   | 2   | 1   |
| 1   | 3   | 1   | 3   |
| 2   | 2   | 7   | 5   |
| 2   | 3   | 5   | 8   |
```